# How does Sound Constitution exactly work?

Tags: rogue-trader, character-advancement

The description says "Gain an additional wound", and also says that the number (which I assume is the x2, x3 number that follows the skill) means the times you have purchased the skill, so does this mean that SCx3 means that you have purchased the abiliy three times, and therefore you have +3 wounds? I would assume it works like this, but when you look at the Arch-Militant advances, the class comes with SC(no number) by default. Then, at level 2 you can purchase SCx3... without ever purchasing SCx2. Then for the next two levels or so you can purchase SCx2 various times. Then, does the number mean you gain 2 wounds for SCx2, and 3 for SCx3? Then, the SC the Arch-Militant starts with would mean he gains one extra wound?

All of this sounds confusing since the description says "gain an additional wound", not "wounds".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrasing is, as I understand, shorthand for how many times you can acquire the talent - it means that at Rank 2 you can get one additional wound, three times; not three wounds at once.

My groups have always ruled that each is treated as a separate advance, so if you have 600xp you can get 3 wounds, but if you only have 200xp you can get 1 wound and save up for the other 2 later.

It would be a bit OP to have 3 additonal wounds for just 200xp :)

Comment: That makes a load of sense! Now I understand how the "Acquire Psychic Techniques" work, they have the same "notation" (x2, x3). Thank you so much, you killed two birds with one stone! (Or may I say two orks with one bolt?)

Answer (score 4):

Each time you take Sound Constitution, you gain 1 Wound.

Where a career rank lists SC (x2), that means you can take it twice in that rank, gaining 1 Wound each time.